# Preserve self-closing tags on extraction

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

Consider the following example:

```
<case>
   <outer>
    <inner>test</inner>
    <inner>test &amp; test <br /><br />test</inner>
    <inner></inner>
   </outer>
</case>
```

I would like to extract the string enclosed within the second *inner* element while preserving *br* tags (or preferably getting them as \n), but decoding all the HTML encoded characters.
That is, I would like to get:

```
"test & test \n\ntest"
```

or

```
"test & test <br /><br />test"
```

So far I have tried the following. It seems to decode the HTML encoded chars but removes 
 tags completely.

```
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(file);
    XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
    var cas = xDoc.Descendants().First(e => e.Name.Equals(ns.GetName("case")));
    foreach (var row in cas.Elements())
    {
        var columnVals = row.Elements(ns.GetName("inner")).Select(e => e.Value);
        string str = columnValues.Skip(1).First();
        // str == "test & test test"
        // but i want:
        // "test & test \n\ntest" or "test & test <br /><br />test"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load(file);
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
var cas = xDoc.Descendants().First(e => e.Name.Equals(ns.GetName("case")));
foreach (var row in cas.Elements())
{
    var columnVals = row.Elements(ns.GetName("inner")).Select(e => e.Nodes());
    var str = columnVals.Skip(1).First();
    var stringResult = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string.Join(" ", str));
}
```

It gets the nodes as strings, but decodes any HTML escaping.

The output is:

```
test & test  <br /> <br /> test
```